# One IP address per virtual terminal "screen" on Ubuntu

Tags: network-programming, ip, ubuntu-14.04, virtualization, squid

I have multiple public IP address and I need to associate one per virtual terminal "screen".

Example:

IP 1: `screen -dmS nameScreen1 ffmpeg etc...`
IP 2: `screen -dmS nameScreen2 ffmpeg etc...`
IP 2: `screen -dmS nameScreen3 streamlink etc...`
IP 2: `screen -dmS nameScreen4 youtube-dl etc...`
IP 3: `screen -dmS nameScreen5 ffmpeg etc...`

I thinked about using X-Forwarded-For in --header to associate a private IP per "screen". With Squid or Network-manager write something like: For private IP 1 use public IP 1. But I don't know if it can works and how to do it.

I would be grateful if you have an other idea to solve this problem too.

Thanks to help me with this :).

Comment: Networking configuration is a *machine* property, not a session or user property.  Multiple `screen` sessions on the same machine cannot have different networking configuration.  You could probably do something like you describe by means of separate virtual machines hosted on your target machine, but `screen` is far short of that.

Comment: Hum, if multiple screen are in same networking configuration with multiple public IP, I just need a configuration to associate a specific screen to a variable and this variable to a specific public IP no? That's why i thinked about using private IP as variable with Squid, Network-manager or an other app and associate this private IP to a screen with X-Forwarded-For if it does that.

Comment: you're missing the point.  *There is no association between networking configuration and processes* other than that processes use the networking configuration of their host system.  Multiple processes (e.g. `screen` processes) running on the same host provide the same networking configuration to processes they themselves launch.  If, with sufficient privilege, you modify the machine's network configuration from one screen, the effect is global.  `screen` is not a substitute for a virtual machine.

Comment: Specific processes you may launch, from within `screen` or otherwise, can choose which IP address to use from among the available ones, but `screen` does not provide a mechanism for masking which ones are available to choose from.

Comment: :/ thanks a lot for your answers. I thinked networking configuration permited to associate a public IP to a type of processus. So i wanted change this condition "this type of processus = this public IP" to the condition "this private IP = this public IP" or an other variable gave in a screen. So I understand that for example it's impossible to do: for the processus "ffmpeg" use this public IP.

Comment: Correct.  Specific commands may offer a means to tell them which IP to use -- i.e. a command-line argument or a configuration file -- but the system offers no *general purpose* mechanism for doing that other than the system's overall configuration.  Moreover, even if `screen` itself had such a mechanism, that would not extend to other processes launched from within a `screen` instance.

Comment: Ok, to be sure to understand: are you sure that if I use `ffmpeg` with `--header X-Forwarded-For=1.2.3.4` I can't have a networking configuration with "for private IP 1.2.3.4 use 192.372.187.189 public IP" ? ^^'

Comment: I am not an expert on `ffmpeg`, but neither it nor `screen` supports a `--header` option as far as I can determine.  It sounds like you may have X11 forwarding in mind, but that has nothing directly to do with `screen` or `ffmpeg`.  In any case, associating an IP number with a *process* is a far different proposition than associating one IP number with another.

Comment: Yes but i thinked that associate a specific process like a session of `ffmpeg` with a virtual IP at launch and associate this virtual IP with a public IP in networking configuration can do the job. I wanted to use a virtual IP as a variable. Perhaps an other type of variable can do it and perhaps I can't associate a virtual IP at launch of a specific process. I saw `X-Forwarded-For` used with `livestreamer`, it doesn't do what I think?

Comment: You keep coming back to the idea of associating an IP number with a specific process, and I keep telling you that **the system provides no general-purpose method of doing such a thing**.  The ability to form such an association, if it exists, is an aspect of the particular program running in the process.  `ffmpeg` does not have such an ability as far as I can determine.

Comment: Following up @JohnBollinger's suggestion of virtual machines: you might be able to use a container (a la docker, LXC) for this too as network configuration can vary per-container. Containers are a bit lighter weight than full virtual machines. There will be a significant learning curve to this though. RedHat has a good intro here: https://www.redhat.com/en/containers

Comment: Hmm... Indeed, thinking about this some more, a "network namespace" might do more or less what you want without a full container. You could exec your screen processes within separate network namespaces, each appropriately configured. See these posts for a start: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/ and http://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2016/04/10/network-namespaces/ (I have no direct experience doing this so can't really help further.)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answers I will try to understand how network namespace and containers works :).