# One public IP address per Namespace

Tags: command-line, namespaces, network-programming, ip, ubuntu-14.04

How can I configure my network to associate one public IP address per Namespace in my Ubuntu 14.04 server and launch it in command line?

I want to do that:

configuration:

```
nameSpace1 = publicIP1
nameSpace2 = publicIP2
nameSpace3 = publicIP3
```

Terminal:

```
nameSpace1 ffmpeg etc...
nameSpace2 ffmpeg etc...
nameSpace2 youtube-dl etc...
nameSpace2 streamlink etc...
nameSpace3 ffmpeg etc...
```

Thanks a lot to help me :)

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://askubuntu.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I tried but i didn't find the flag "namespaces" in superuser so..

Comment: did you look at http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com ?.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried with this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/879045/fake-one-ip-adress-per-thread but they ask me the relevance to ubuntu ^^'.

Comment: back to superuser.com ? When I searched for `[linux] namespace` it shows 115 Q/As. 93 for `[linux] namespaces` . Unfortunately, for many cases, the Stackexchange system is not the place designed to answer your Q. I assume you have looked at other sites besides those here on StackExchange? There is also `chat` (per topci) here on S.O., but I haven't really used it much. If you find the right channel you might find a helpful soul. If this is for school, you should reach out to fellow classmates and any others that could help. Good luck!

Comment: And ... it's called 'chat room' and you need a rep of 20 to have access to that. See if you can answer a few new questions here OR post a Q that is more on topic per the links in my first comment. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I looked other sites but I am in love for Stackexchange and I think that my problem is very basic and the système is really great to expose it for all after me. I really don't understand that I can't find a simple way to associate a public Ip address to a process without complexe brige with containers or virtual machines. A lot of people searched that and impossible to have a clear tuto :/.

Comment: Did you noticed the comment at the end of this [RedHat Blog post about user namespaces](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/07/07/whats-next-for-containers-user-namespaces/) ? ("In case someone else comes here from google trying to figure out how to use user namespaces...") .  I think you'll need an admin to "turn on" user namespaces. Are you an admin, or will your organization allow the use of namespaces? In large organizations, that can be a very time consuming process. Good luck.

Comment: Per responses to your previous Q, seems like containers is the technology you should be researching. Given the number of Qs here on S.O. for similar problems, I don't think it is super easy to get right the first time. Maybe it's time to rethink your approach OR at least reset expectations of those hoping to get this done "tomorrow" ;-/ . Good luck! ;-)

Comment: Yes, you right @shelter ^^'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One IP address per virtual terminal "screen" on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026740/one-ip-address-per-virtual-terminal-screen-on-ubuntu)